# Frequent ORA-4068 Error in webLogic 12c after rebuilding the package in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, datasource, weblogic12c

I am running my web application WAR in WebLogic 12c. I configured my JNDI JDBC Data Source using Data Source option at admin console. Everything was working fine until I removed some privileges from stored procedures. After that I am getting error `ORA-04068: existing state of packages string has been discarded`. 
But nothing is able to solve the issue. Could any one please suggest me any resolution to the above issue ? Any help would be appreciated.

1. Clear the statement cache in webLogic

2. Reset the connection in webLogic

3. Set Statement Cache Size to 0

4. Finally restart the server using command line

5. Deleted the conflicting package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to solve this issue. It was because of timestamp mismatch error in Oracle Database. [Resolution found here](http://oracleelogs.blogspot.com/2013/08/to-identify-and-resolve-database.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the SERIALLY_REUSABLE pragma on the package spec/body to limit this problem.  This may incur a bit of a performance hit.  Also, you cannot use this method if the package has variables whose state needs to be retained between different sessions calling the package.

More details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/seriallyreusable_pragma.htm#LNPLS01346).

Comment: thank you for the response . But currently I do not have any package configured in my schema now. I think it may be Weblogic Issue. Could you please suggest me anything related to weblogic?